# QT pimpl inheritance from QObject

Tags: qt, inheritance, private

While going through Qt code I had this basic question on the pimpl implementation.
As an example taking QWidget implementation.

```
QWidget        ---inherits---> QObject
   |                              |
 contains                      contains
   |                              |
  \ /                            \ /
QWidgetPrivate ---inherits---> QObjectPrivate
```

Now QWidget has two instances of QObjectPrivate (through inheritance and through containment).
Why was the implementation done in this way? Isn't it an overhead to have two instances of the same object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There aren't two instances of `QObjectPrivate` when instantiating a `QWidget`.  If you look closely at the header file for `QObject`, you'll notice a protected constructor:

```
protected:
    QObject(QObjectPrivate &dd, QObject *parent = 0);
```

Which sets the instance of QObjectPrivate to that passed in via the protected constructor:

```
QObject::QObject(QObjectPrivate &dd, QObject *parent)
    : d_ptr(&dd)
```

This is the constructor called by all of the different `QWidget` constructors.  The QWidget constructor passes in an instace of `QWidgetPrivate` which, as you noted, is a subclass of `QObjectPrivate`.  Thus, only one instance of QObjectPrivate exists in QWidget.

Here's the default `QWidget` constructor that illustrates this:

```
QWidget::QWidget(QWidget *parent, Qt::WindowFlags f)
    : QObject(*new QWidgetPrivate, 0), QPaintDevice()
{
    QT_TRY {
        d_func()->init(parent, f);
    } QT_CATCH(...) {
        QWidgetExceptionCleaner::cleanup(this, d_func());
        QT_RETHROW;
    }
}
```